# Division has to get hide for multiple

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

When i click on view (id) that row has to get disappear and as usual that panel-body division has to show that is working fine because of accordion. I need to do this for on click of view (id) has to hide for multiple divisions can any one give me the suggestions how to do this

**This is my html page**

```
  <div id="accordion">    
        <div class="row" id="view">
            <span class="col-md-4">Mobile Number</span>
            <span class="col-md-4">7894561236</span>
            <span  class="col-md-4">Edit</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body ">
            <div class="row accordion-panel-bg">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

                    <label  class="col-md-4">Mobile Number</label>     
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="hidden" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no; ?>" />
                        <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $row->mobile_no; ?>"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                        <!--                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <span class="col-md-4">Password</span>
            <span class="col-md-4">XXXXX</span>
            <span  class="col-md-4">Edit</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body ">
            <div class="row accordion-panel-bg">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

                    <label  class="col-md-4">Password</label>          
                    <div class="col-md-8"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $row->password; ?>" />
                        <input type ="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                        <!--                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is the script i have used**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
        });
    $("doccument").ready(function(){
        $("#view").click(function(){
        $("#view").hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please take care about the question tags on stackoverflow. I've removed the 'php' tag since the question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Document without the extra c, and shouldnt be an string

Comment: Okay, Thank you. But, i have mentioned the php tag because my code is also having php code

Comment: No problem. :) The published code snippets actually do not contain relevant PHP pieces. If you edit your question and add some of your relevant PHP code, so the quesion belongs to a PHP problem, you can add the tag again at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest the following:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });
  $("#view").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

This will hide the `#view` element. There would be no way to unhide it, so if the user navigates to another panel, they won't be able to return. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/przndthk/

This seems a bit odd in my mind. You may want to consider something more like: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/przndthk/3/